# How to perform mouse move event on cross domain frames in a page and read data related to that element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, google-chrome-extension, cross-site

I am trying to read content from the frame in chrome extension. I am able to perform 'mouseover' event inside frame if the frame is of the same domain as that of the page. I have followed below approach to perform mouseover event on elements inside a frame of the same domain.

```
function FrameMousemove(iframe) {
     iframe.contentWindow.addEventListener('mousemove', function (event) {
         alert(event.srcElement.innerHTML);
     });
};

FrameMousemove(document.getElementById("IF1"));
```

By using this code when I move the mouse onto any element inside frame an alert is displaying with innerHTML of mouse hovered element. I want similar functionality for cross-domain frames. Is that possible? If not can anyone let me know why?

Comment: Simply declare/inject a content script in that iframe. It'll have access to the iframe DOM. Further info should be easy to find AFAIK.

Comment: @wOxxOm How can i inject content script in particular frame ?

Comment: If that iframe is inside a tab then you can use chrome.tabs.executeScript. If it's inside a non-tab page like the background/browserAction page then you'll have to declare a content script in manifest.json - and you can even limit it to a particular iframe if you can modify the iframe URL by adding a dummy parameter. I think this was answered somewhere, but either way it's something you can come up with by just reading the documentation.

Comment: @wOxxOm Ok, I reopened it. If you can find another more relevant duplicate, please do as I'm sure this has been asked and answered many times.

Comment: Because if you could do that you can trick people to open your site with amazon.com in a frame and steal heir credit card details.